# How to retrive decorated test function name and arguments in a pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to run the decorated test manually in its fixture, can I do that?
for example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):
    call test_my_function
    call test_my_fucntion again

def test_my_function(my_fixture):
    pass
```

The user-case is as below:
We want to make a test framework, in which we have setup and teardown phase, and a special target: we want to run the test twice times between setup and teardown. That's because we have a common refreash function, it will reconstruct the database of the test, we want to confirm everything are unchanged after refresh. So there should be two times test before and after the refresh function call.

I want to know how to get function name and arguments, and run it manually

Comment: The purpose of a fixture is to provide setup *for* a test, not *be* at test. What's the use-case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `getfullargspec` (from `import` `inspect`):

```
import inspect
argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(test_my_function)
print(argspec.args)
```

Outputs:

```
['my_fixture']
```

or just:

```
print(test_my_function.__code__.co_varnames)
```

Outputs:

```
('my_fixture',)
```

To get the `__name__`s of the functions:

```
print(my_fixture.__name__)
print(test_my_function.__name__)
```

Outputs:

```
my_fixture
test_my_function
```

If you want to get the `args` and `__name__` of the `pytest` decorated function `my_fixture` we can use `@pytest.mark.parametrize`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize
def my_fixture(request):
    pass

def test_my_function(my_fixture):
    pass

test_my_function(my_fixture)
print(my_fixture.__code__.co_varnames)
print(my_fixture.__name__)
```

Outputs:

```
('request',)
my_fixture
```

To continue using the `pytest.fixture` decorator we can add a `parametrize` attribute `pytest.mark.parametrize` to it:

```
pytest.fixture.parametrize = pytest.mark.parametrize

@pytest.fixture.parametrize
def my_fixture(request):
    pass

def test_my_function(my_fixture):
    pass

test_my_function(my_fixture)
print(my_fixture.__code__.co_varnames)
print(my_fixture.__name__)
```

Outputs:

```
('request',)
my_fixture
```